# Visual Studio Code is not responding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Ubuntu 23.04. I installed VSCode from Ubuntu Software. When I launch VSCode via the terminal or by clicking the icon in the Show applications menu Visual Studio Code is not responding

OS info:

[image: OS info]

Comment: @guiverc i added screenshot check please and its amd ryzen 7 3700u cpu incase you need it